# How to use Web Workers with Webextensions?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to use a web worker in my webextension to make things run faster, but I can't seem to get even the demo webworker example that MDN provides to work. This is my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "sharedTest.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is sharedTest.js:

```
console.log("js loaded");
if (window.Worker) { // Check if Browser supports the Worker api.
    // Requires script name as input
    var myWorker = new Worker(browser.runtime.getURL('testWorker.js'));
    myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('Message received from worker');
    console.log(e.data);
    };
  myWorker.postMessage([42, 23]); // Sending message as an array to the worker
  console.log('Message posted to worker');
}
```

and this is testWorker.js:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Message received from main script');
  var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
  console.log('Posting message back to main script');
  postMessage(workerResult);
}
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or if there is anything missing in my manifest, that'd be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out, due to the same-origin policy, you can't use normal web workers in webextensions. However, you can get around this by wrapping your worker in a blob like so:

```
var blob = new Blob([
    `onmessage = function(e) {
       console.log('Message received from main script');
       var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
       console.log('Posting message back to main script');
       postMessage(workerResult);
     }`]);

// Obtain a blob URL reference to our worker 'file'.
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from worker');
    console.log(e.data);
};
  worker.postMessage([42, 23]); // Sending message as an array to the worker
  console.log('Message posted to worker');
```

And that will work. The above example was based on [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-enviornment-subworkers), and that does work in webextensions (for theoretically everything but Internet Explorer). However, that blob worker is not within the same origin as the rest of your extension anymore, so due to the same-origin policy, the global importScripts() will not work to import any files in your extension. This means that you have to include all necessary methods and logic within the Blob, which is less than ideal.

Alternatively, I realized that this is kind of what [background scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts) are for, or for my case, [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

Answer (score 3):

It may be an old question, but in case anyone is looking for a solution other than using blobs or background scripts, this might be it - without caveats.

If you attempt to load your WebWorker with your current manifest.js, you will get an error. However, you can add your worker.js file as an additional resource, so that your browser can access it. You can do this by adding [web_accessible_resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources) key to your manifest.json. NB: the path specified as value to the key will be relative to the manifest file.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "MyExtension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": [ "js/content.js", "js/import.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "css": ["css/style.css"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "js/worker.js", "pictures/cat.svg" ]
}
```

You can then obtain the runtime url of your worker from your content.js to create the worker:

```
const worker = new Worker(browser.runtime.getURL('js/worker.js'));
worker.onmessage = (e) => {window.console.log(e);
```

To import a script to your worker, you first need to specify it as a content script in your manifest (path relative to manifest). Then in your worker you can import it as:

```
self.importScripts('import.js');
self.onmessage = (e) => importStuff.doWork(e);
```

The path to your import script here is relative to the worker file itself.

That's it - enjoy threading in extensions.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be possible to create Workers from the background page! While the original question looked like they were trying to use a content script that feature does not seem to be available.

Here's a dumb unimaginative example for spawning a web worker on the background page:

*manifest.json*:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "background": { "page": "background.html" }
}
```

*background.html*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

*background.js*:

```js
if(window.Worker)
{
    const myWorker = new Worker(browser.runtime.getURL('worker.js'));

    myWorker.onmessage = function(msg) {
        console.log("Main Script: Message received", msg.data);
    }

    let i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {myWorker.postMessage({num: i++});}, 500);
}
else
{
    console.log("Worker's not supported :(")
}
```

*worker.js*:

```js
onmessage = function(msg) 
{
    postMessage({timestamp: Date.now(), passedData: msg.data});
}
```

If you need to use a content script then you can use [ports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/Port) to send messages from the script to the background page and back again.